# Images getting blurred when converting Word to pdf document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, conversion

My thesis is written in word and I have figures all with 600dpi or higher. On Word the figures look very clear but when converted to PDF (In word I select File -> Save As -> PDF) figures get blurred. I have tried several things but could not find a solution. As it was suggested in some online posts I have set in Word-> Options-> Advance -> Image size and Quality as 'Do not compress images in file'.
I tried 'print to pdf' as well. Then as there were online suggestions to use PrimoPDF tried using that as well. But nothing worked. Any help to convert to PDF without having blurred images will be helpful as the submission deadline is near.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Not sure if you have already tried the following. After the Save/Save As dialog window has appeared and selecting PDF as type, click on Options. Select "Optimize for image quality. Click OK. Save the file.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I just tried it. Still it did not improve image quality

Comment: Get Adobe Acrobat or Nitro PDF.  *Your thesis*.  Surely the university has resources that will help you.

Comment: Can you give example (screenshot) because if you have high quality images is impossible to get bad PDF

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "Optimize for" setting in the Publish as PDF dialog window before publishing. Click File->Export->Create PDF, then change the setting from "Minimize size" to "Standard".

[MS Word Publish as PDF dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTGvM.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried 'print to pdf' as well. Then as there were online suggestions to use PrimoPDF tried using that as well.

Based on my experience, you may install a free Foxit PDF Reader.

Go to File > print > choose "High Quality Print" and browse and set the correct folder to save the PDF files > Edit > Set "Off" for all Compression, besides set options as following image shown > Click OK to save print configuration file.

[image]

Go back to Print, use Foxit Reader PDF Printer to convert a document to PDF file.